# RxJava: как подписаться на данные из другого потока?

Tags: rxjava

Хочу подписаться на ответ, полученный на запрос из сети.

Допустим у меня есть такой интерфейс:

```
interface Net {
    // Посылает запрос в сеть, а когда приходит ответ
    // дергает callback в своем сетевом потоке
    void sendRequestGetResponse(String request, Consumer<String> responseCallback);
}
```

Но я не хочу обрабатывать данные в сетевом потоке, мне надо обрабатывать их в нужном потоке, например в моем ThreadPoolExecutor.

И хочется сделать что-то такое:

```
Observable<String> observable = <как то создали свой observable, я не знаю как>;

// Подписались на обработку ответа в нужном executor
observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(executor)).subscribe(response -> {
    System.out.println("received response " + response);
});

net.sendRequestGetResponse("hello!", response -> {
    // Получили ответ и положили его в observable
    observable.push(response);
});
```

Как это правильно делается с помощью RxJava?

Comment: Судя по всему, вам нужен `observeOn`. События будут доставляться туда, куда вы скажете.

Comment: Я догадываюсь что нужно что-то такое, и даже попытался это сделать с помощью observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(executor)).

Мне непонятно, как полученный в сетевом потоке response засунуть в мой observable.

Comment: Не, вам нужен именно `observeOn`. `subscribeOn` производит _подписку_ в потоке, который вы указали. А `observeOn` доставляет события в поток, который вы указали.

Comment: Ах, вот оно что. Спасибо, пусть будет observeOn.
Но как все таки ответ из сетевого calback переложить?

Comment: Ну, `observable.observeOn(<куда-вы-там-хотите-переложить>).subscribe(response -> { System.out.println("received response " + response); });`, судя по всему. (У меня компилятора нет под рукой, чтобы проверить, так что помогайте.)

Comment: В качестве первоначального Observable возьмите хоть Subject (наверняка есть более идиоматический путь, но и Subject покатит)

Comment: А, я кажется начинаю врубаться. Попробую написать ответ к своему вопросу. Но вообще что-то голова идет кругом от изучения этого rx.

Answer (score 1):

После некоторого обдумывания кажется понял, как это делать:

```
net.sendRequestGetResponse("hello!", response -> {

    Observable.just(response).
            observeOn(Schedulers.from(executor)).
            subscribe(response1 -> {
                System.out.println("received response " + response1 +
                    ", thread = " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            });
});
```

По крайней мере тест напечал то что требуется.

Comment: А если вместо `Observable.just` всё же взять всё же один `subject`?

Comment: Я попробовал заменить на PublishSubject.<String>create() - тоже работает.

Comment: Идея в том, чтобы вы создали Subject **один** раз. Тогда `sendRequestGetResponse` будет в него плеваться сообщениями, а подписка и приём может проходить в другой части программы.

Comment: Да, так тоже работает.
Я вынес PublishSubject.<String>create() наружу и кладу в него ответы в sendRequestGetResponse. Подписка ловит.